# Check the stored / cached WP_Query with transients on post change

Tags: wp-query, loop, cache, transient, private

right now I have WP_Query stored for 24h (1day) with set_transient function. Everything works fine like it should. But if for example I change the post which is in the stored array to private or modify its meta_value, the post will still be seen on frontend.

Any way to check if the post values have been modified? or I should use some other function for that?

The code:

```
if (false === ($loop = get_transient('randomizeProfiles'))) {
    $loop = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'portfolio',
        'posts_per_page' => 18,
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array('key' => 'move_to_archive','compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'),
            array('key' => 'move_to_archive', 'value' => '0', 'compare' => '=')
        )
    ));
    $hour = carbon_get_theme_option('posts_hours');
    $time = 60 * 60 * $hour;
    set_transient('randomizeProfiles', $loop, $time);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the save_post hook to check if a post that is being saved is a portfolio page and reset the transient.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'reset_portfolio_transient', 10,3 );

function reset_portfolio_transient( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    // Only set for portfolio post_type
    if ( 'portfolio' !== get_post_type($post) ) {
        return;
    }

    // delete old tranisent
    delete_transient( 'randomizeProfiles' );

    // reset your transient
    set_portfolio_query_tranisent();
}
```

`set_portfolio_query_tranisent()` being the code you already provided.

If you edit portfolio pages often this is not a great solution. You might want to read the wordpress codex on transients for an alternative.

Comment: Thank you! will check what I can do :)